# Hibernate 4, EnversIntegrator could not be instantiated

Tags: java, hibernate, configuration

I'm trying to set up Hibernate, and since 4.0.0 just came out I naturally decided to go with that. It seems that no matter what way I try to create a SessionFactory, it always leads to the same error:

**Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.hibernate.envers.event.EnversIntegrator could not be instantiated: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.hibernate.envers.event.EnversIntegrator to org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator**

It seems like there is something wrong with my Hibernate configuration but I can't figure out what. Here's my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://192.168.0.17:5432/mydb</property>
        <property name="connection.username">myusrname</property>
        <property name="connection.password">mypasswd</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- c3p0 configuration -->
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Does anyone spot anything out of the ordinary, or do you have other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found no way to get Hibernate 4.0.0 CR4 working. Switching to 3.6.7 resolved the problem and works just fine. I conclude that there must be some bug in the release, and will file a bug report.